# Podio PHP API - Filter item collection by calculated field value

Tags: php, podio

I have a calculated field with external id `has-email` which populates with the value `1` if the item's `email` address is not empty (and `0` if it is).

```
$filters = array (
    'has-email' => 1
);

$attributes = array (
    'filters'       => $filters
);

$collection = PodioItem::filter( $app_id, $attributes );
```

I'm trying to get a collection of items which includes only those with an email address (where the value of `has-email` is `1`), however, this returns the error `Podio Error Invalid value 1 (integer): must be object`. How can I filter on calculated field value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the value as an array with `from` and `to` keys.
Also please make sure the Calculation field `has-email`'s value in Podio is a **number**(not a string).

The below code will return the items where the value of `has-email` is 1

```
$filters = array(
    'has-email' => array(
        'from' => 1,
        'to' => 1
    )
);
```

and the below code will return the items where the value of `has-email` is 0

```
$filters = array(
    'has-email' => array(
        'from' => 0,
        'to' => 0
    )
);
```